# Should's or shoulds

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, should

I can't figure out for the life of me if it should be "should's" or "shoulds."

It's a follow up sentence of saying, "that's a lot of should's."

(there was also question as to whether the period should go inside or outside of the quotation mark after should's)

I looked over the link of Is "’s ” ever correct for pluralization? but still couldn't figure out what the solution would be to my question. Being more direct of whether it should be should's or shoulds would be more helpful, thanks!

Comment: So rather than take two seconds to actually provide a definitive answer of the two possible options, someone instead has chosen to just mark it as a duplicate question that has already been answered in a previous post. It's bizarre, and certainly not helpful whatsoever, to say the least.

Comment: This question *is* a duplicate of the other, so it was handled appropriately. As for the question, it's a matter of style. It used to be common style to use *do's and don't's* (although most people left off the final apostrophe in the second word). Currently, it's more common to not use an apostrophe: *dos and don'ts*. For treating words as words, it's also more common to use italics rather than quotation marks. And some common phrases—like dos and don'ts—can be left in plain unadorned roman text. In short, there is no definitive answer.